# How to detect memory leakage in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm training a VGG11 from scratch, and I keep getting "Out of memory" in my GPU even though i clean the GPU entirely.

```
    self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    lr_dict = {100: 0.01, 150: 0.001}
    self.optimizer = optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)
    result_per_epoc = list()
    train_acc = 0.0
    train_loss = 0.0
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        debug_memory(f"Train epoc {epoch} START", clear_mem=True)

        if epoch in lr_dict.keys():
            for gopt in self.optimizer.param_groups:
                gopt['lr'] = lr_dict[epoch]
        epoch_time_start = datetime.now()

        for batch_idx, (images, labels) in tqdm(enumerate(iter(traindata_loader)), total=len(traindata_loader)):
            images = images.to(self.device)
            labels = labels.to(self.device)
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            try:
                outputs = self.model(images)
            except Exception as e:
                debug_memory(f"On crash", clear_mem=True)
                print(f"Batch ID: {batch_idx}")
                raise e
            loss = self.criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()

            train_accuracy = accuracy(outputs, labels)
            train_acc += float(train_accuracy)
            train_loss += float(loss)

            del images, labels, loss, outputs
            clear_memory()
        debug_memory(f"Train epoc {epoch} TRAIN", clear_mem=True)
        train_acc /= (batch_idx + 1)
        train_loss /= (batch_idx + 1)
```

Up to line "debug_memory(f"Train epoc {epoch} START", clear_mem=True)" I used 3,499/11,019 (31%) of my memory. But after a few batchs my code crashes on memory even though i delete everything i've added to the GPU and in "clear_memory" I did this:

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
gc.collect()
with torch.no_grad():
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
gc.collect()
```

The model i'm using is "vgg11_bn" from torchvision.models

What else am I missing?

Comment: Try `loss.detach()` while you add it to `train_loss`. If you don't detach such tensors from the computation graph, references are maintained to it which will persist even after that iteration ends (scope of variable ends) and thus GPU memory won't be released. In case, this doesn't solve it, you may also want to check your accuracy function and ensure that no such references get maintained (i.e. use `.detach()` on all the tensors).